# How to prove basic sequence properties

Tags: haskell, category-theory

As I understand it, one way to express that something is a free monoid is with a class like this:

```hs
class (Foldable s, forall a. Monoid (s a)) => Sequence s where
  singleton :: a -> s a
```

and the following "universal construction" laws:

For any `Monoid m` and any function `f :: a -> m`,

1. `foldMap f . singleton = f`
2. `foldMap f` is a monoid morphism.
3. `foldMap f` is the only function satisfying both 1 and 2.

Is this understanding correct?

If so, it would be nice to be able to use these laws to prove basic sequence properties. We can define

```hs
data ViewL s a
  = EmptyL
  | a :< s a

instance Sequence s => Semigroup (ViewL s a) where
  EmptyL <> y = y
  x <> EmptyL = x
  (x :< xs) <> (y :< ys) = x :< (xs <> singleton y <> ys)

instance Sequence s => Monoid (ViewL s a) where
  mempty = EmptyL

viewl :: Sequence s => s a -> ViewL s a
viewl = foldMap (:< mempty)
```

How would I show the following?

1. `viewl s = EmptyL ==> s == mempty`
2. `viewl s == a :< s' <==> s == singleton a <> s'`

The converse of 1 follows immediately from `foldMap f` being a monoid morphism for all `f`, but I don't really know how to approach the above.

Comment: I think it will be helpful to prove a lemma showing that all elements of your free monoid are generated by `<>`-combinations of `mempty` and `singleton x`.

Comment: @AlexReinking, any idea how to do that? My first thought (unrelated) was that it might be helpful to prove that for any `Sequence`s `s` and `t`, `foldMap @s (singleton @t) . foldMap @t (singleton @s) = id`, but I haven't worked out how to get there yet. Similarly, `foldMap @s (singleton @s)` should be `id`. Both of these would presumably follow from your suggested lemma.

Comment: @AlexReinking, this isn't a *huge* concern for me, but wouldn't a proof that the free monoid is generated as you indicate be inherently non-constructive (and hence inadmissible in intuitionist logic)? It would seem you'd need to suppose the existence of an element *not* generated by the basic ones and refute that.

Comment: Are you trying to mechanize the proof in something like Coq? If so, you didn't say... not sure why else a non-constructive proof would be an issue.

Comment: A sketch: suppose there were some element `m` that cannot be constructed as I described. You could construct a `foldMap'` that satisfies (1) and (2), but acts differently from `foldMap` on `m`. This contradicts (3).

Comment: @AlexReinking, no, I'm not trying to formalize a proof, but it's always nice to know the contexts in which a theorem holds.

Comment: @AlexReinking, I'm pretty sure the uniqueness law for `foldMap` ends up being sufficient to avoid excluded middle. As you can see from my edits, I seem to be getting pretty close to a (very long) proof.

Comment: @AlexReinking, success! In the end, I didn't need to prove nearly as many lemmas as I started with, and I even avoided messing with `[]` at all.

Answer (score 3):

We will begin with a couple general lemmas about `foldMap` and `singleton`. The first lemma apparently follows from parametricity for any `Foldable`, but we can prove it directly for sequences using their laws.

Lemma (`foldMap` composition): Suppose `Sequence s`, `Monoid m`, and `Monoid n`. Let `f :: a -> m` be a function and let `g :: m -> n` be a monoid morphism. Then

```
g . foldMap @s f = foldMap @s (g . f)
```

Proof:

```
g . foldMap @s f . singleton @s
= -- foldMap/singleton
g . f
```

By the uniqueness of `foldMap`,

```
g . foldMap @s f = foldMap @s (g . f)
```

---

Lemma (rebuilding): For any `Sequence s`, `foldMap @s (singleton @s) = id @s`.

Proof: `id @s . singleton @s = singleton @s`. By the uniqueness of `foldMap`, `id @s = foldMap @s (singleton @s)`.

---

Next, we will rewrite the `Semigroup (ViewL s a)` instance in a form that will prove easier to work with in the following. Just a bit of equational reasoning (using general `case` transformations and the monoid identity law) are sufficient to show that the following instance is equivalent (ignoring laziness, as I will throughout).

```
instance Sequence s => Semigroup (ViewL s a) where
  EmptyL <> y = y
  (x :< xs) <> v = x :< (xs <> unviewl v)

unviewl :: Sequence s => ViewL s a -> s a
unviewl EmptyL = mempty
unviewl (x :< xs) = singleton x <> xs
```

---

Lemma: `unviewl` is a monoid morphism.

Proof: We must show that `unviewl mempty = mempty` and that for any `v1` and `v2`, `unviewl v1 <> unviewl v2 = unviewl (v1 <> v2)`. The first is trivial.

```
unviewl @s mempty
= -- def of mempty for ViewL s
unviewl @s EmptyL
= -- def of unviewl
mempty
```

For the second, we work by cases:

First case:

```
unviewl (EmptyL <> v2)
= -- definition of <> (or the monoid law)
unviewl v2
= -- monoid law
mempty <> unviewl v2
= -- definition of unviewl
unviewl EmptyL <> unviewl v2
```

Second case:

```
unviewl ((x :< xs) <> v)
= -- definition of <>
unviewl (x :< (xs <> unviewl v))
= -- definition of unviewl
singleton x <> xs <> unviewl v
= -- definition of unviewl
unviewl (x :< xs) <> unviewl v
```

---

Next, we show that `viewl` and `unviewl` are (full) inverses.

Lemma: `unviewl . viewl = id`

Proof:

```
unviewl . viewl
= -- definition of viewl
unviewl . foldMap (:< mempty)
= -- foldMap composition lemma and the fact that unviewl
  -- is a monoid morphism.
foldMap (unviewl . (:< mempty))
=
foldMap (\x -> unviewl (x :< mempty))
= -- definition of unviewl
foldMap (\x -> singleton x <> mempty)
= -- monoid law and eta reduction
foldMap singleton
= -- rebuilding lemma
id
```

Lemma (`viewl` of `singleton`): For any `a`, `viewl (singleton a) = a :< mempty`.

Proof:

```
viewl (singleton a)
= -- definition of viewl
foldMap (:< mempty) (singleton a)
= -- foldMap/singleton law
a :< mempty
```

Lemma: `viewl . unviewl = id`

Proof: Let `v :: ViewL s a`. We proceed by cases on `v`.

First case:

```
viewl (unviewl EmptyL)
= -- definition of unviewl
viewl mempty
= -- viewl is a monoid morphism (because it is a fold)
mempty
= -- definition of mempty
EmptyL
```

Second case:

```
viewl (unviewl (x :< xs))
= -- definition of unviewl
viewl (singleton x <> xs)
= -- viewl is a monoid morphism
viewl (singleton x) <> viewl xs
= -- viewl of singleton lemma
(x :< mempty) <> viewl xs
= -- definition of <>
x :< (mempty <> unviewl (viewl xs))
= -- monoid law
x :< unviewl (viewl xs)
= -- by lemma above, unviewl . viewl = id
x :< xs
```

---

Okay! Now we have all the pieces we need.

Corollary: If `Sequence s`, `xs :: s a`, and `viewl xs = EmptyL`, then `xs = mempty`.

Proof: By assumption, `viewl xs = EmptyL`. Thus `unviewl (viewl xs) = unviewl EmptyL`. Since `unviewl . viewl = id` and by the definition of `unviewl`, `xs = mempty`.

Corollary: If `Sequence s`, `x :: a`, and `xs :: s a`, then `viewl (singleton x <> xs) = x :< xs`.

Proof:

```
viewl (singleton x <> xs)
= -- viewl is a monoid morphism
viewl (singleton x) <> viewl xs
= -- lemma above
(x :< mempty) <> viewl xs
= -- definition of <>
x :< (mempty <> unviewl (viewl xs))
= -- monoid law and unviewl . viewl = id
x :< xs
```

Corollary: If `viewl xs = y :< ys`, then `xs = singleton y <> ys`.

Proof: Applying `unviewl` to both sides of the premise, `unviewl (viewl xs) = unviewl (y :< ys)`. Since `unview l . viewl = id` and by the definition of `unviewl`, the theorem holds.

---

I have proved all I set out to. On my way to discovering these proofs, I proved several other things about this formulation of `Sequence`. I have collected them [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/43444c618431a1d51101cedd642c88c2).